# My Minecraft Mod (version 1.7.10) does not work in MinecraftEdu

Tags: minecraft, minecraft-forge

I made my Minecraft Mod which is 1.7.10 and it works perfectly in Minecraft when i install it in both the server and client. But, when I put my .jar file in the Mods folder of the server of MinecraftEdu, the game crashes. Is there something needed for minecraftEdu? Thank you in advance.

Comment: Can you please [edit] your question to include the full crash report?  Also, do you have the mod installed on both the client and the server?

Comment: Yes sure :) Here is the gist of the crash report in minecraftedu/servertool/server/crash-reports: 
https://gist.github.com/SaraFatih/b1040fffe48c058e4662cbabefe0a409
And concerning the installation, I have installed the Mod both at the client side and the server side.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that MinecraftEDU has a different structure than Minecraft itself. You might want to try and decompile MinecraftEDU, or look at the error log, to see your problem(Its that `net.minecraft.client.entity.EntityClientPlayerMP` is not in MinecraftEDU).

Comment: Alright I see.. But how can I decompile MinecraftEDU?

Comment: I believe that forge decompiler decompiles from a folder in the root folder of itself, but if not, you might be able to use a setting to get the MinecraftEDU sourcecode.